unhandled System.NullReferenceException: on debug clean .net coreweb api / exception at System.Buffer.Memmove(Byte& dest, Byte& src, UIntPtr len)
i have last vs 2022 17.10.5 no updates possible
when i do new > asp.net core web api > some location >

create
and hit debug with no change
then it open browser with url https://localhost:7125/swagger
ahd it do not open because of ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
and in console of .net i see
      Unhandled exception while processing 0HN5MOO0P5675.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at System.Buffer.Memmove(Byte& dest, Byte& src, UIntPtr len)
         at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials& inCredentials, SafeDeleteSslContext& refContext, ContextFlags inFlags, Endianness endianness, InputSecurityBuffers inSecBuffers, SecurityBuffer& outSecBuffer, ContextFlags& outFlags)
         at System.Net.SSPISecureChannelType.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, InputSecurityBuffers inputBuffers, ContextFlags inFlags, Endianness endianness, SecurityBuffer& outputBuffer, ContextFlags& outFlags)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials& credentialsHandle, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer, ProtocolToken& token)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessTlsFrame(Int32 frameSize, ProtocolToken& message)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationWithTelemetryAsync(Boolean isAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection`1.ExecuteAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unhandled exception while processing 0HN5MOO0P5676.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at System.Buffer.Memmove(Byte& dest, Byte& src, UIntPtr len)
         at System.Net.Security.SafeDeleteContext.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials& inCredentials, SafeDeleteSslContext& refContext, ContextFlags inFlags, Endianness endianness, InputSecurityBuffers inSecBuffers, SecurityBuffer& outSecBuffer, ContextFlags& outFlags)
         at System.Net.SSPISecureChannelType.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, InputSecurityBuffers inputBuffers, ContextFlags inFlags, Endianness endianness, SecurityBuffer& outputBuffer, ContextFlags& outFlags)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcceptSecurityContext(SafeFreeCredentials& credentialsHandle, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer, ProtocolToken& token)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessTlsFrame(Int32 frameSize, ProtocolToken& message)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationWithTelemetryAsync(Boolean isAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)

why is that / what i did wrong / how to trubleshot this ?
thanks and regards !

for future searchers. solution was
dotnet dev-certs https --clean

dotnet dev-certs https --check

dotnet dev-certs https 

dotnet dev-certs https --trust

no idea what was wrong here befor and why this was failing but this helped.

Fantastic - worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Try to find launchsettings.json file, and find this section.

Solution
Change the order of the applicationUrl, it's ①② in the screenshot, change it to ②①.
Workaround
Use IISExpress, instead of https.

